# Angular: ngOnChanges method cannot access dynamically set instance properties

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Can anyone explain why this.agGrid is undefined in the ngOnChanges method?  It is being set in onGridReady which is executed before the ngOnChanges method.

In my component.ts file

```
  private onGridReady(agGrid) {
    this.agGrid = agGrid  // set property
    console.log(1, this.agGrid)

  }
  ngOnChanges(changed) {
    console.log(2, this.agGrid)  // property undefined
  }
```

console output:

```
1 Object { type: "gridReady", api: {…}, columnApi: {…} }
2 undefined
```

Any idea why this.agGrid is not defined in ngOnChanges?

**Edit (showing how onGridReady is called):**

html

```
<ag-grid-angular
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

more of the ts file

```
  private createGridOptions() {
    const gridOptions = {};
    gridOptions['onGridReady'] = this.onGridReady;
    return gridOptions;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.gridOptions = this.createGridOptions();
  }
```

Comment: How is `onGridReady` being called?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks `ngOnChanges` runs first always and `onGridReady` runs at a later point in time. Looking at your console logs, it could be that an `input` changes later and causes `ngOnChanges` to run.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  The issue is that when an action is performed on the page, ngOnChanges is called at a later time and logs undefined.  As you can see from the console output, 2 is called after 1.

Comment: @user2263572 Can you answer my question?

Comment: It's an ag-grid callback function that is executed after the grid has been initialized.  Don't know much more than that.

Comment: Yes... but surely some other part of your code refers to it?

Comment: didn't think it mattered, but updated the question to include that code.

Comment: @user2263572 It is crucial to the problem. Added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the function directly. This is effectively the same as calling `onGridReady` inside a `function() { }`. Inside a `function() { }`, the keyword `this` refers to the function itself.

You are not updating the `agGrid` property on the component - you are setting a property on the function itself.

If you want to refer to the outer scope - the component in this case - you should use an arrow function.

```js
gridOptions['onGridReady'] = (agGrid) => this.onGridReady(agGrid);
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay79o3

In this demo, button 1 will never set the `name` property on the component due to how it is called. Button 2 will set the `name` property on the component because it is called inside an arrow function.